# Android Jetpack Navigation Component - Back button closes the Searchview instead of navigating to previous screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview, navigation-architecture

I am using the Android Jetpack Navigation Component for navigating between fragments back and forth. On one Fragment, I have a SearchView in expanded form. When I press the back button (to the left of the SearchView), then the following happens:

1. **the SearchView will be first closed instead of navigating to the previous screeen**
2. **I need to press the back button a 2nd time to navigate to the previous screen**

Why is that ? Why it does not navigate directly to the previous screen?

Here, you can see the code in the fragment handling the SearchView-related code:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {

        // add a search view to the menu
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchItem.expandActionView()

        searchView.apply {
            queryHint = "Search"
            isIconified = false

            /* this shows the query the user has typed (no submission) so that the user can see which search query was used */
            setQuery(args.query, false)

            doOnLayout {
                this.clearFocus()
            }

            setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    
                    // do some stuff with the query ..
                    return false
                }
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean = false
            })
        }
    }
```

Here, you can see the `search_menu.xml` file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- SearchView -->
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

    <item android:id="@+id/profile_icon"
        android:title="@string/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/account"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

What do I need to add to my code so that the app directly navigates back to the previous screen when I press the back button without closing the SearchView first ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"`.

[`collapseActionView` means](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource#:%7E:text=The%20action%20view%20associated%20with%20this%20action%20item%20(as%20declared%20by%20android%3AactionLayout%20or%20android%3AactionViewClass)%20is%20collapsible.%0AIntroduced%20in%20API%20level%2014.) that the back button first closes the search view. You have press the back button a second time to navigate to the previous screen.

Answering your question, remove `collapseActionView` from `app:showAsAction` and you'll get the behavior you want (pressing the back button will navigate to the previous screen).

But then you might also want [to programmatically close the keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911469/hide-keyboard-when-navigating-from-a-fragment-to-another), since it stays open when navigating to the previous screen.